# Recently viewed products block at bottom of products list page -magento

Tags: magento-1.5

I would like to display recently viewed  products block at bottom of page in Product list page (out of left, content and right block) . It must display from left to right side of page  ,i search in many forums but i'm not getting right answer can any one help me please

Answer (score 2):

Would you like to show it on 'Product View Page', if yes, then you can change the xml file like this, comment out the bit which display it on right and write this (Assuming ur using Magento's latest 1.6.x versions,)

```
  <catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This should display the 'Recently Viewed Products' on your product page in the main content area.

Comment: Could you more explain i am new